# VB.NET compare two text files and add insufficient lines

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for solution to compare two text files and add insufficient lines from second file into first. Here is an example.

First file content:

```
<category = Names>
Anton
Darell
Kate
</category>
<category = Job title>
Director
President
Manager
</category>
<category = other>
bla bla
lia lia
ohoho
</category>
```

Second File Content:

```
<category = Names>
Anton
Frank
Thomas
</category>
<category = Job title>
Driver
President
Manager
</category>
<category = other>
bla bla
olia olia olia
</category>
```

If you have noticed every file has some type of categories, so I want to add new object from SECOND File into the same categories in First File so new file should look like this:

```
<category = Names>
Anton
Darell
Kate
Frank
Thomas
</category>
<category = Job title>
Director
President
Manager
Driver
</category>
<category = other>
bla bla
lia lia
ohoho
olia olia olia
</category>
```

Hope this is solvable.

Comment: Basically you want to write a diff (comparison) tool that will also do merges?  There is already software out there that will do this for you (BeyondCompare is one we use at my work, but there are others).

Comment: This should be easily do-able.  Show us what you have tried already and we should be able to show you how to complete it.

Comment: I was thinking to use function split, so I could split every category in two files and then compare them, adding insufficient lines and thn writing all the categories back into one file. I am beginner in VB, this is why I asked is this is possible :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private mResult As New List(Of String)

Public Sub MergeFiles()
    ReadFile("C:\File1.txt")
    ReadFile("C:\File2.txt")
    WriteFile("C:\Result.txt")
    mResult.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub ReadFile(ByVal Path As String)
    Dim mSR As New System.IO.StreamReader(Path)
    Dim mItem As String = ""
    Do While Not mSR.EndOfStream
        mItem = mSR.ReadLine
        If Not mResult.Contains(mItem) Then mResult.Add(mItem)
    Loop
    mSR.Close()
    mSR.Dispose()
End Sub

Public Sub WriteFile(ByVal Path As String)
    Dim mSW As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Path)
    For Each mItem As String In mResult
        mSW.WriteLine(mItem)
    Next
    mSW.Close()
    mSW.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn`t work. It doesn`t create even Result.txt file. I am not sure, what`s the problem.

Comment: Do you get an error in the code above, and when, at what line do you get it? Or deos ist run and just the files won´t be created?